# Equivalent function of 'get_pattern' of R in python, required for calculating all the different patterns of string in a column of data frame

Tags: r, python-3.x, regex

In R, there is a bpa (basic pattern analysis) package using which I can get the frequency of pattern in a column of data frame. Function get_pattern extracts the pattern from the data column. All the numeric values are represented by ‘9’, lowercase and uppercase represented by ‘a’ and ‘A’, and special characters remain same.

For example if the following is the data frame (df):

```
   Gender             Date         Phone
  Female        16Aug2001   571 972 510
   Male       2009-08-21   090 875 285
      M       01/22/2004 (079)-200-150
   male       09/02/2008 (129)-006-808
   Male February 19 2006   016 651 851
 Female        16Nov2015 (492)-455-108



df$Date %>%
  get_pattern %>%  # extract all the unique patterns
  table %>%        # calculate the frequencies of unique pattern
  as.data.frame    # display as a data frame

                   . Freq
         99/99/9999  259
         9999-99-99  262
          99Aaa9999  241
  Aaaaaaaaaw99w9999   19
```

Is there an equivalent in python as well to get the unique set of patterns in a column. The column will have alphanumeric characters along with special characters.  Once the pattern has been identified, I can focus on patterns with highest frequency to standardize them

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce the behavior as you described (and detailed in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bpa/vignettes/introduction.html)) with a few regexes. After the substitutions use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the count of each unique occurrence.

> The core function in `bpa` is `get_pattern`. This function is used to extract patterns from a vector
> of data. This function will transform the values so that all numeric digits are represented by the character `9`. Similarly, all lowercase and uppercase letters are represented by the characters `a` and `A`, respectively. Everything else (e.g., special characters like `-`, `@`, `#`, etc.) remains the same. The only exception are whitespace characters which are represented as `w` if `show_ws = TRUE` (by default). This can be changed to any character string using the `ws_char` option.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")

WS_CHAR = "w"

df = df.replace(r"\d", "9", regex=True)
df = df.replace(r"[A-Z]", "A", regex=True)
df = df.replace(r"[a-z]", "a", regex=True)
df = df.replace(r"\s", WS_CHAR, regex=True)

# create a new dataframe for each column of the original df
df_freq = []
for i in df.columns:
    p = df[i].value_counts().rename("Freq")
    d = pd.DataFrame(p)
    df_freq.append(d)
```

Ouput for **Gender**, **Date** and **Phone** frequencies

```
        Freq   |                     Freq   |                  Freq
Aaaaaa     2   |   99Aaa9999            2   |   999w999w999       3
Aaaa       2   |   99/99/9999           2   |   (999)-999-999     3
A          1   |   9999-99-99           1   |
aaaa       1   |   Aaaaaaaaw99w9999     1   |
```